# Python regex sub not working as expected when using alternatives in square brackets

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, replace

I'm trying to replace dates in a string with `<Month Year>` using the Python `re` module.

I tried:

```
import re
s = "Wikipedia articles containing buzzwords from April 2014\t23"
s = re.sub(r"[January|April|March]\s+\d{1,4}", "<Month Year>", s)
```

However it returns:

```
'Wikipedia articles containing buzzwords from Apri<Month Year>\t23'
```

instead of what I expected:

```
'Wikipedia articles containing buzzwords from <Month Year>\t23'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `[...]` is a character class. Your regex is looking for a character in `JanuryApilMch|`. Change it to `(?:...)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets means alternative within its members (chars) you need parenthesis. Try this:

```
s = re.sub(r"(January|April|March)\s+\d{1,4}", "<Month Year>", s)
```

Quick example here:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Wikipedia articles containing buzzwords from April 2014\t23"
>>> s = re.sub(r"(January|April|March)\s+\d{1,4}", "<Month Year>", s)
>>> s
'Wikipedia articles containing buzzwords from <Month Year>\t23'
```